# Magento : Empty cart page and checkout page error

Tags: php, magento, checkout, cart, magento-1.9

I have issue on the magento 1.9.0.1

i got this error on the check out page i have try many solution from the google but not working for me so can you please suggest some good idea.

```
Invalid method Mage_Page_Block_Html::addItemRender(Array
(
    [0] => bundle
    [1] => bundle/checkout_cart_item_renderer
    [2] => checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml
)
)

Trace:
#0 [internal function]: Varien_Object->__call('addItemRender', Array)
#1 [internal function]: Mage_Page_Block_Html->addItemRender('bundle', 'bundle/checkout...', 'checkout/onepag...')
#2 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(348): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(214): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateAction(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#4 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/code/community/IWD/Opc/Block/Wrapper.php(31): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#6 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/opc/wrapper.phtml(54): IWD_Opc_Block_Wrapper->_getReviewHtml()
#7 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(260): include('/homepages/0/d5...')
#8 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(291): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#9 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(305): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#10 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#11 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#12 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#13 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#14 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#15 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/design/frontend/shopper/default/template/page/1column.phtml(56): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#16 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(260): include('/homepages/0/d5...')
#17 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(291): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/shoppe...')
#18 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(305): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#19 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#20 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#21 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#22 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/code/community/IWD/Opc/controllers/IndexController.php(127): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#23 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): IWD_Opc_IndexController->indexAction()
#24 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#25 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#26 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#27 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#28 /homepages/0/d530282576/htdocs/shop/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#29 {main}
```

I have also one error on my cart page it just display empty. I have tested with template hint and it just show that like bellow

```
frontend/base/default/template/catalog/msrp/popup.phtml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issue. I have just make back up of my checkout template folder and checkout.xml of current theme and copy checkout folder and checkout.xml from the base and it works for me.

My be its my theme issue. I have issue shopper theme. and in the layout folder there is not any xml of checkout.